# Retrieving image from asset folder - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoapods, cocoapods-app

I'm writing a class to build a cocoapods and I want to get the image I placed in `Assets.xcassets`. The problem is always getting `nil` image. Are there anything I miss?

Here is my `podspec` file :
[image]

Here is the directory stucture : 
[image]

This is what I try to load the Image:

```
#import "HaloImage.h"

@implementation HaloImage
- (void)showImage {
    NSBundle * bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:self];
    NSURL * bundleUrl = [bundle URLForResource:@"Assets" withExtension:@"bundle"];
    self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:bundleUrl.absoluteString];
}
@end
```

Comment: i believe that as long as the assets are included in the projectfile you should be able to call all assets inside it

Comment: so do I, but in fact I can't display the image I want.

Answer (score 2):

You can access image from Assets.xcassets by this. Give it a try

```
UIImage *image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"image name without extension"];
```

Comment: Or, if there's a folder in place `UIImage *image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"folder/image_name_without_extension"];`

Answer (score 0):

you can use image from asset or  main bundle only by name (png file)

```
self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"name_of_image"];
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, i actually had try that code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code :

```
@implementation HaloImage
- (void)showImage {
    NSBundle * bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:self];
    NSURL * bundleUrl = [bundle pathForResource:@"Assets" withExtension:@"bundle"];
    self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:bundleUrl.absoluteString];
}
@end
```